# Live Agent Custom Chat Issue error Interact is down for maintenance Sorry for the inconvenience

Tags: apex, visualforce, liveagent, pre-chat-api

I am getting the above error when my user tries to start a chat and fills up the pre-chat form page. Now, when the user navigates from pre chat to custom chat page to start the chat error occurs.

In the above error "Interact is my Site". 
Also, when i try to start chat without adding custom chat page in my live agent settings i.e. "Chat Button & Automated Invitations" the error doesn't appear and the functionality works fine.

Hope Anybody could share an opinion on the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the custom chat window is accessible to the public (through the site).